# Как запретить дублирование строки?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Можно ли запретить вставлять значение в таблицу, если вводимое значение уже есть в некотором столбце? Необходимо, чтобы значения не повторялись. Как такого добиться?

Comment: повесить ключ UNIQUE на колонку/связкуКолонок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В MS SQL есть несколько вариантов которые приводят к ограничению на уникальность:

1. Явно задать ограничение при создании таблицы

   CREATE TABLE MyTable
    (
      ID int NOT NULL, 
      CONSTRAINT AK_MyTable UNIQUE(ID) 
   );
2. Если таблице уже есть, создаем уникальный индекс по полю:

   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indexID ON MyTable (ID);
3. Или делаем ALTER таблицы и добавляем ограничение:

   ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT cons_MyTable UNIQUE (ID)

Все действия дадут одинаковый результат.
Ответ по MS SQL добавлен с соответствием метке вопроса.

Comment: спасибооо как раз мне были интересны оба случая.Шикарный и внятный ответ